# AWS Glue: Read/ Write parquet files(Files>50,000)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

We are getting around 50,000 parquet files. The path is partitioned. Below is the structure:

**brand/client/year/month/day**

There are around 5 files per partition. We are currently reading these files using dynamic frames and aggregating(daily/weekly/monthly) the data. The job takes around 12 hrs. As per my investigation, it takes a long time to read/write parquet files. I tried to read the files using spark.read but I get slow down error( (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: 503 Slow Down; Request ID: X0DCWKCSVGV5JN0T; S3 Extended Request ID: ro2vUXGcqDEPB9zlRuXJapWBAhKpx4Az3Nzn+U8mIAQ1T9DQSvrJKmS9vo82jOipNs2/uAK0a0Y=; Proxy: null)). Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Glue is actually not performing that well as it advertises. We had a similar problem: the workflow with our ETL jobs took to long to evaluate and therefore we switched to StepFunctions + Athena. This needs to build some custom logic, but these workflows are extremly performant comparing to Glue. Additionally You can use partitioning projection in order to speed up the queries and not having to update the metadata in Glue Catalog. If You have to stay with Glue do not forget to use the job bookmarks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code that you were using to identify and read those files, and the _exact_ error. Also, is this 50,000 files in total or per day (or some other measure)? And how large are the individual files?

Comment: Some background on this is that during the creation of a dynamic frame,  or a data frame spark will create a list in memory of all the files to be included and then once it’s completed it’s going to create the object